# Combine grep output when piping

Tags: awk, grep

I use the following command `sipcalc` to display information about an IP:

```
sipcalc 192.16.12.1/16 | grep -E 'Network address|Network mask \(bits\)'
```

The output is:

```
Network address     - 192.16.0.0
Network mask (bits) - 16
```

Is  there a way to combine the above output (only the right part), so the output would be:

```
192.16.0.0/16
```

I have my own way to do this by separating grep call and then concatenate the result, but I don't think it is a good solution. Can grep or any other commands that can be used to pipe the output like `awk` in order to obtain the output above?

Comment: With GNU `sed`, you could use `sed -zE 's/.*Network address[[:space:]-]*([0-9.]+).*Network mask \(bits\)[[:space:]-]*([0-9]+).*/\1\/\2\n/'`

Comment: Can u explain how does that work ? The sed command above looks complicated.

Comment: Nothing complicated: matches the whole text, captures digit/dot parts after two known substrings and joins the captured texts with `/`, which is the replacement. What do you expect? You did not explain how you plan to "combine" the strings.

Comment: OK, I think I understand that .. it will filter digit parts. But, can grep alone do this ? or maybe awk

Comment: I edited my question with much details that focuses on the same problem. Someone misunderstood that I'm asking multiple questions in the same post above, and he voted to close this down. I don't think I ever asked multiple questions? Why don't you explain. That is so sad with the power of clicking. That is  just an abuse of power. Might be the same person who always voting down my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` is *not* really an ideal tool for doing operations beyond just searching for your expected text. Use `awk` alone!

```
awk '/Network address/{ ip = $NF } /Network mask \(bits\)/{ print ip "/" $NF}'
```

Awk processes records in `/pattern/ { action }` syntax. So when the first pattern in matched, extract the last field delimited by space `$NF` i.e. a special variable Awk uses to store the value of last column when delimited by space ( See [7.5.1 Built-in Variables That Control awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/User_002dmodified.html))

When the second pattern is matched in a similar way, join that last field with the value stored in `ip` variable. The `+` just concatenates the individual strings to produce the desired result.

Comment: I got a question, why did you escape the string that is not special character and you put `'\'`  in front? Example `/Network\ address` and ``/Network\ mask\``. I have to remove these to make it work. It is understandable that you escape the special characters like `\(bits\)` . So this is the one that work: `awk '/Network address/{ ip = $NF } /Network mask \(bits\)/{ print ip "/" $NF}'`

Comment: @KalibZen: yes you are right - a space can simply be represented as itself (a literal) in regular expressions in awk